# Workspace Indicator for Cinnamon

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cinnamon

I was wondering is there a "Workspace Indicator" for Cinnamon because I always forget which workspace I am.

[Here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/21/workspace-indicator/) is what I found for GNOME. I am not sure whether it works for Cinnamon. Besides, it would be better if it could show my custom name for each workspace.

[example of workspace indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry4OH.png)

Comment: "Workspace Name" mentioned at the end of the answer is what the question asks for. IMO better mention at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the System Settings, look at the Applets icon.  There are several that provide workspace indicators.  One called Workspace Switcher puts a window icon (rectangular box) in the system tray for each workspace.  It contains a visual representation of what's in that workspace and highlights the active one.  Hovering on an icon displays the workspace name, so if you hover on the highlighted one, it will identify it (you can also tell from its position). You can use it switch between them.  I believe it is installed by default.

[image]

In this screenshot, System Settings is open in Workspace 1.  At the bottom of the shot is the system tray, with the three defined workspaces represented on the right of the image.  The System Settings window (which is actually in the middle of the screen but the image is cropped), is represented by a white rectangle in the Workspace 1 icon, which is highlighted by a white border.

From the System Settings, Workspaces icon, there is a switch to Enable Workspace OSD (On-Screen Display).  If that is on, it will briefly display the workspace name when you switch.

Back on the Applets icon, the Available Applets tab contains a couple of others that you can load.  One called Workspace Name looks similar to your example.

Answer (score 0):

"Workspace Name" applet (https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/222) was mentioned in accepted answer as "looks similar to your example". My answer is to explain in details how to use it:

Download, extract folder `workspace-name@willurd` to `/.local/share/cinnamon/applets/`. Restart Cinnamon via Ctlr-Alt-Esc.

To change names to custom edit dconf via command in terminal:

`gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences workspace-names "['name1','name2','name3','name4']"`.

Also one can edit how names are dispayed, I have changed a line in javascript to change text on the panel:

```
let name = 'ws-'+ (activeWorkspace.index()+1); //Main.getWorkspaceName(activeWorkspace.index());
```